# Declaration merging for asseting non-null

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, typescript-typings

I'd like to tweak this from @types/aws-lambda to express our intention that `pathParameters` is not null and have the specific format.

```js
export interface APIGatewayProxyEventBase<TAuthorizerContext> {
    body: string | null;
    headers: APIGatewayProxyEventHeaders;
    multiValueHeaders: APIGatewayProxyEventMultiValueHeaders;
    httpMethod: string;
    isBase64Encoded: boolean;
    path: string;
    pathParameters: APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters | null;
    // ...snip...
}
export interface APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters {
    [name: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

In our application code, we can denote fooId is not null

```js
declare module "aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy" {
  export interface APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters {
    fooId: string;
  }
}

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event) => {
  // This is still needed
  if (!event.pathParameters) {
    throw new Error("parameter is empty");
  }
  // Without declaration merging, fooId is string | undefined 
  // but is now string
  const { fooId } = event.pathParameters;
```

In order to remove `if (!event.pathParameters)`, I wrote this:

```js
declare module "aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy" {
  export interface APIGatewayProxyEventBase<T> {
    pathParameters: APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters;
  }
  export interface APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters {
    fooId: string
  }
}
```

and following error is given.

```
error TS2428: All declarations of 'APIGatewayProxyEventBase' must have identical type parameters.
error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'pathParameters' must be of type 'APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters | null', but here has type 'APIGatewayProxyEventPathParameters'.
```

Can `event` be of type `{ pathParameters: { fooId: string }, ... }` not `{ pathParameters?: { fooId: string }, ... }` ?

Comment: Declaration merging doesn't allow arbitrary modification of the merged type... for something like this you might want to look into just providing your own version of the library typings in question instead of importing the original ones.  I don't know if anyone has any better answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Omit` [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to accomplish this.

```
interface LambdaEvent extends Omit<APIGatewayProxyEventV2, 'pathParameters'> {
  pathParameters: { fooId: string }
}
```

and then type the event argument in your handler with the modified `LambdaEvent` type

```
export const handler: Handler<LambdaEvent, APIGatewayProxyResultV2> = (event) => { ... }
```

This is documented with examples in the handler types [file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/handler.d.ts#L32)

Comment: I would like to `type APIGatewayProxyHandler = Handler<APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult>;` work with tweaked `APIGatewayProxyEventBase` automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by automatically. Can you elaborate? You can see how types are defined here to understand how they can be modified/ used - https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/aws-lambda/trigger/api-gateway-proxy.d.ts

Comment: @yskkin I added a link to the types file where this approach is documented with examples. Let me know if there is any additional information I can supply for this answer to be accepted.